# horizontally align anchor images from vertical css sprite

Tags: html, css, css-sprites

I have 4 images in a css vertical sprite that I want each become a `href`'s on my page going horizontal. Starting at `left:250px` `top:2px` and with padding of `3px` between each image.

CSS

```
.sprites {
    background:url('/pic/sprites.jpg')no-repeat top left;
    width:36px;
    height:36px;
}
.sprites.sprites.twitter {
    background-position:0px 0px;
}
.sprites.sprites.facebook {
    background-position:0px -46px;
}
.sprites.sprites.google-plus {
    background-position:0px -92px;
}
.sprites.sprites.pinterest {
    background-position:0px -138px;
}
.social {position:relative;left:250px;top:2px;}
```

I can figure out how to start in `250px` from the left and `2px` from the top, but I can not figure out how to get the images going horizontally as a `href`'s with padding of `3px`

html

```xml
<div class=social>
<a href="http://www.example.com"><div class='sprites google-plus'></div></a>
<a href="http://www.example.com"><div class='sprites facebook'></div></a>
<a href="http://www.example.com"><div class='sprites twitter'></div></a>
<a href="http://www.example.com"><div class='sprites pinterest'></div></a></div>
```

Comment: can you put it in a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add display: inline-block/block; depending on what you want to achieve, this should work for you

Comment: I attempted both inline-block and block and neither worked.  Nothing changed.

Comment: have you tried applying `vertical-align` middle to the anchor tag?

Comment: I've made this Jsfiddle for you, used a placeholder image http://jsfiddle.net/Lq7Ne/